# printer rediscovered, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: printing, 20.04

My network printer (HP Envy 5644) is constantly (2-3 times a day) being added to my computer (Acer Aspire 5) giving me a notification, even if it's already installed. Earlier I have edited `/etc/cups/cups-browsed.conf` and changed `BrowseRemoteProtocols` from `dnssd cups` to `none` to avoid this; if I try that now (with Ubuntu 20.04)  I end up with no printer at all. Nothing alarming really (and the printer is working), but I don't like the software acting "unfinished" this way. Anyone?